# I2C Packet ocasionally send a garbage data

Tags: i2c, arduino-due, code-review, serial-data

I have a project with Arduino working as I2C slave.
The master request data each 300ms.

The code of Arduino is:

```
/*
  Name:     SimpleClass_Applcation.ino
  Created:  5/26/2017 4:18:28 PM
  Author:   Felipe Fonseca
  Description: Versão de Código para o Trocador de Calor de forma a simplificar
  a operçãoo para tornar possível a utilização em aulas
*/

//includes

//Libs dos sensores
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Ultrasonic.h>

//display lcd
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//timed action
//#include <Utility.h>
//#include <TimedAction.h>

//lib i2c
#include <Wire.h>

//gerar sinais
#include <waveforms.h>

//Pinos de entrada e sa�da

#define but1 A1  //no programa de testes 42; no original, trocar por A1  //
#define but2 A2  //no programa de testes 44; no original trocar por A2
#define pot A0 //no programa de testes A7; no original trocar por A0

#define mode_switch 42  //no programa de testes 43; no original trocar por 42
#define emergency_button 43 //no programa de testes 51; no original  trocar por 43

#define ultrassonico_echo   50      //no original trocar para 50
#define ultrassonico_trigger 48     //no original trocar para 48
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 52             //no original trocar para 52  - terminal do conjunto de sensores
#define hf_sensor 9                //no original trocar para 9 -> pino de interrup��o para calculo da vaz�o agua fria
#define TEMPERATURE_PRECISION 12


#define led1 44                  // utilizado para sinalização geral
#define led2 45                  // utilizado para sinalização geral
#define led_heater 47            // no programa de testes 37; no original trocar para 47

#define inversor_rele 49        //no programa de teste 47;no original trocar para 49
#define heater_rele 10          //no programa de testes 49;no original trocar para 10

#define MAX_MENU_ITENS 2         //numero de telas no menu

//testes em prototipo
#define LDR_PIN A3
#define LM35_PIN A4
#define RXLED 3
#define oneHzSample 1000000/maxSamplesNum //gerador de sinais
#define SIMULATORSAMPLETIME 500

float LM35_value;
float LDR_value;

//vari�veis internas

//armazenar valores de entrada
bool switch_state;
int pot_value;
bool emergency_status;

volatile int pump_onoff;
volatile int heater_onoff;
volatile float remote_pumpspeed;

float temp[4];
double vazao_quente;
float vazao_fria;
volatile int flow_frequency;


//estrutura de dados para envio i2c
typedef struct processData {
  float temp1;
  float temp2;
  float temp3;
  float temp4;
  float hotflow;
  float coldflow;
  float pump_speed;
  byte bstatus;
  byte chksum;
};

typedef union I2C_Send { //compartilha a mesma área de memória
  processData data;
  byte I2C_packet[sizeof(processData)];
};


I2C_Send send_info;
int command; //processar o indice de comando enviado pelo Rpi

//array de bytes auxilar para receber a velocidade da bomba
byte data[4];

//estrutura para receber um float para alterar velocidade
typedef union PumpDataSpeed {
  float fspeed;
  byte bspeed[4];
};

//variáveis utilizadas no calculo de vazao de agua fria/quente
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long cloopTime;
long microsec;
float cmMsec;
float nivel;
//float vazao1_sf;   //se for necessário para a função de vazao quente, descomentar

//variáveis auxiliares para operação local
char flag_button1 = 0x00;
char flag_button2 = 0x00;
char flag_emergency = 0x00;
String mode = "";

//variáveis auxiliares para comando
float pot_value_mapped;

//variáveis para o simulador
unsigned long current_sim_time;
unsigned long simulator_time_elapsed;
int indexwave;

//inicialização de objetos
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DeviceAddress deviceID[] =
{
  { 0x28, 0xFF, 0x46, 0x02, 0x54, 0x16, 0x04, 0xF8 },
  { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xD3, 0xE6, 0x53, 0x16, 0x04, 0xA0 },
  { 0x28, 0xFF, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0x53, 0x16, 0x04, 0x65 },
  { 0x28, 0x1D, 0x9D, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x2E }
};
//delay necessário para leitura dos sensores. Depende da resolução
int delayTempRead = 0;
int lastTempRequest = millis();

Ultrasonic ultrasonic(ultrassonico_trigger, ultrassonico_echo);

LiquidCrystal lcd(41, 11, 12, 40, 13, 38);  //no original deve-se utilizar  LiquidCrystal lcd(41, 11, 12, 40, 13, 38);

//funções
void ReadPotentiometer();
float mapfloat(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max);

//funções de navegação  - Display LCD
void Menu(int op);
void EmergencyStatus();

//funções de leitura de grandezes
void flow();                //função de interrupção para o calculo de vazao de água fria
void PumpSpeed(float ref);  //função para alterar a velocidade da bomba
void VazaoAguaFria();       //função para calcular a vazão de água fria
void VazaoAguaQuente();     //função para calcular a vazão de água quente
void Temperaturas();        //função para calcular as temperaturas dos sensores
void new_Temperaturas();

//funções do estado do arduino
void LocalState();
void RemoteState();
void emergencia();

//funções para fazerem a leitura periodica dos valores analógicos
void runReads();
void refresh_I2C_Packet();

//função para receber o valor em bytes via i2c e retornar a velocidade em float
void parseSpeed(byte data[]);

//testes em prototipo
void Temperaturas2();
void Simulator();

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  //painel
  pinMode(but1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(but2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pot, INPUT);
  pinMode(mode_switch, INPUT);
  pinMode(emergency_button, INPUT);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led_heater, OUTPUT);

  //sensores
  pinMode(ultrassonico_echo, INPUT);
  pinMode(ultrassonico_trigger, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(hf_sensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ONE_WIRE_BUS, INPUT_PULLUP);

  //reles
  pinMode(heater_rele, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inversor_rele, OUTPUT);

  //começar inversor desligado
  digitalWrite(inversor_rele, HIGH);

  //habilitar a interrupção para medição de vazão fria
  //attachInterrupt(hf_sensor, flow, RISING);

  //iniciar sensores de temperatura
  sensors.begin();
  for (byte i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    sensors.setResolution(deviceID[i], TEMPERATURE_PRECISION);
  }
  //modo de leitura assincrona
  //sensors.setWaitForConversion(false);
  delayTempRead = 750 / (1 << (12 - TEMPERATURE_PRECISION));

  //iniciar lcd
  lcd.begin(20, 4); //no original utilizar 20,4

  //resolução de escrita do DAC
  analogWriteResolution(10);

  //variáveis que guarda o status da bomba e do aquecedor
  pump_onoff = 0;
  heater_onoff = 0;

  //inicialização da serial
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //inicialização de variáveis
  vazao_fria = 0;
  vazao_quente = 0;

  //inicialização da estrutura i2c
  send_info.data.chksum = 27;
  Wire.begin(12); //arduino iniciado no endereço 12
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); //callback para recebimento de comandos
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); //callback para responder à requisições

  //semente para o simulador
  randomSeed(analogRead(LM35_PIN));
  indexwave = 0;
}


// the loop function runs over and over again until power down or reset
void loop() {

  // le o estado da chave
  switch_state = digitalRead(mode_switch);

  /* lê se o botão de emergencia está acionado ou não
      cobre os casos de pressionar o botão e despressionar o botão
  */
  if (digitalRead(emergency_button) == LOW) { //presisonado botão
    emergencia();
  }
  else if (!digitalRead(emergency_button) == LOW && flag_emergency) { //despressionado o botão
    flag_emergency = 0x00;
    emergency_status = 0;
    lcd.clear();
    if (switch_state) {
      RemoteState();
    }
    else {
      LocalState();
    }
  }
  else { //tudo normal
    if (switch_state) {
      RemoteState();
    }
    else {
      LocalState();
    }
  }
}

//função de interrupção para calcular a vazão
/*void flow() {
  flow_frequency++;
}*/

//funções que gerenciam o estado do arduino

void LocalState() {

  //efetua a leitura das grandezas
  runReads();

  //atualiza o lcd com os novos valores
  Menu(0);

  if (!digitalRead(but1)) flag_button1 = 0x01;
  if (!digitalRead(but2)) flag_button2 = 0x01;

  if (digitalRead(but1) && flag_button1) {
    flag_button1 = 0x00;
    //troca o estado da bomba
    digitalWrite(inversor_rele, pump_onoff);  //o estado da bomba � invertido
    //digitalWrite(led_pump, !pump_onoff);  -> N�o � para utilizar o led
    pump_onoff = !pump_onoff;
  }

  if (digitalRead(but2) && flag_button2) {
    flag_button2 = 0x00;
    //troca o estado do aquecedor
    digitalWrite(heater_rele, !heater_onoff);
    digitalWrite(led_heater, !heater_onoff);
    heater_onoff = !heater_onoff;
  }

  //controlar a velocidade da bomba
  ReadPotentiometer();
  PumpSpeed(pot_value_mapped);

  //enquanto modo local, a variável remote_pumpspeed deve ser atualizada para quando
  //ocorrer a mudança para o modo remoto, por exemplo, as informações sejam corretas
  remote_pumpspeed = pot_value_mapped;

  //atualiza a estrutura de envio de dados via i2c
  refresh_I2C_Packet();
}

void RemoteState() {
  //faz a leitura das variáveis
  runReads();

  //atualiza o lcd com os novos valores
  Menu(1);

  //atualiza a estrutura de envio de dados via i2c
  refresh_I2C_Packet();
}

void emergencia() {
  //digitalWrite(led_flow_mode, LOW);//Apaga LED 1
  digitalWrite(led_heater, LOW);//Apaga LED 2
  digitalWrite(inversor_rele, HIGH);//Desliga a bomba
  digitalWrite(heater_rele, LOW);//Desliga o aquecedor

  //atualiza variável de emergência
  emergency_status = 1;

  //vari�veis auxiliares
  pump_onoff = 0x00;
  heater_onoff = 0x00;
  remote_pumpspeed = 0.0;

  //para evitar blinkar o lcd
  if (!flag_emergency) {
    lcd.clear();
    EmergencyStatus();
  }
  flag_emergency = 0x01;
}

//funções para gerenciar a exibição do lcd

void EmergencyStatus() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Emergencia");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Comandos");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("Bloqueados");
}

void Menu(int op) {

  mode = (op == 1) ? "Remote Mode" : "Local  Mode";

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(mode);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("TA: ");
  lcd.print(temp[0]);
  lcd.print("  ");
  lcd.print("TB: ");
  lcd.print(temp[1]);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("TC: ");
  lcd.print(temp[2]);
  lcd.print("  ");
  lcd.print("TD: ");
  lcd.print(temp[3]);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
  lcd.print("V1: ");
  lcd.print(vazao_quente);
  lcd.print("  ");
  lcd.print("V2: ");
  lcd.print(vazao_fria);

}

//funções de leitura (e escrita) das grandezas

void Temperaturas() {

  // call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature
  // request to all devices on the bus

  sensors.requestTemperatures();

  // print the device information
  for (byte i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  {
    temp[i] = sensors.getTempC(deviceID[i]);
  }
}

void new_Temperaturas(){
  if(millis() - lastTempRequest > delayTempRead){
    for (byte i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
      temp[i] = sensors.getTempC(deviceID[i]);
    }
  }
  lastTempRequest = millis();
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
}

void VazaoAguaFria() {
  currentTime = millis();
  // Every second, calculate litres/hour
  if (currentTime >= (cloopTime + 1000))
  {
    cloopTime = currentTime; // Updates cloopTime
    // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in L/min.
    vazao_fria = (flow_frequency / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency) / 7.5Q = flowrate in L/min
    flow_frequency = 0; // Reset Counter
  }
}

void VazaoAguaQuente() {

  float vazao1_sf; //descobrir o porquê do nome da variavel

  microsec = ultrasonic.timing();
  cmMsec = ultrasonic.convert(microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);
  nivel = 11.46 - cmMsec;
  vazao1_sf = (0.0537) * pow((nivel * 10), 1.4727);
  if (vazao1_sf > 1) {
    vazao_quente = 0.75 * vazao_quente + 0.25 * vazao1_sf;
  }
}

void Temperaturas2() {
  LM35_value = analogRead(LM35_PIN) * 0.48875855;
  LDR_value = analogRead(LDR_PIN) / 10.0;
  temp[0] = LM35_value;
  temp[1] = LDR_value;
}

void Simulator() {
  current_sim_time = millis();
  if (current_sim_time >= simulator_time_elapsed + SIMULATORSAMPLETIME) {

    simulator_time_elapsed = current_sim_time;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      temp[i] = mapfloat(random(1024), 0, 1023, 10, 50);
    }

    //ultima temperatura com valor senoidal
    temp[3] = mapfloat(waveformsTable[0][indexwave], 0, 4095, 0, 100);
    indexwave++;
    if (indexwave == maxSamplesNum) {
      indexwave = 0;// Reset the counter to repeat the wave
    }

    vazao_quente = mapfloat(random(1024), 0, 1023, 0, 30);
    vazao_fria = mapfloat(random(1024), 0, 1023, 0, 30);
  }
}


void PumpSpeed(float ref) {
  if (ref > 100)
    ref = 100;
  else if (ref < 0)
    ref = 0;
  analogWrite(DAC0, ref * 9.43 + 80);
}

void ReadPotentiometer() {
  pot_value = analogRead(pot);
  pot_value_mapped = mapfloat(pot_value, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
}

void runReads() {

    //Temperaturas();
    //VazaoAguaFria();
    //VazaoAguaQuente();
    //new_Temperaturas();

  //Temperaturas2();
  Simulator();
}


//funções callback do i2c
void receiveEvent(int Nbytes) {
  command = Wire.read();

  switch (command) {
    case 49: //comando de teste
      //comando liga bomba
      digitalWrite(inversor_rele, LOW); //o estado da bomba é invertido
      pump_onoff = 1;
      break;

    case 50:
      //comando desliga bomba
      digitalWrite(inversor_rele, HIGH);
      pump_onoff = 0;
      break;

    case 51:
      //comando liga aquecedor
      digitalWrite(heater_rele, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(led_heater, HIGH);
      heater_onoff = 1;
      break;

    case 52:
      //comando desliga aquecedor
      digitalWrite(heater_rele, LOW);
      digitalWrite(led_heater, LOW);
      heater_onoff = 0;
      break;

    case 53:
      //comando alterar velocidade da bomba
      int i = 0;
      while (Wire.available()) {
        data[i] = Wire.read();
        i = i + 1;
      }
      parseSpeed(data);
      break;
  }
}

void requestEvent() {
  if (command == 54) {
    Wire.write(send_info.I2C_packet, sizeof(processData));
  }
}

void parseSpeed(byte data[]) {
  //o primeiro byte é o número de bytes do envio; deve-se ignorar
  PumpDataSpeed speed;
  speed.bspeed[0] = data[1];
  speed.bspeed[1] = data[2];
  speed.bspeed[2] = data[3];
  speed.bspeed[3] = data[4];
  //Serial.println(speed.fspeed);
  remote_pumpspeed = speed.fspeed;
  PumpSpeed(remote_pumpspeed); //envia o comando de velocidade para a bomba fisicamente
}

void refresh_I2C_Packet() {
  send_info.data.temp1 = temp[0];
  send_info.data.temp2 = temp[1];
  send_info.data.temp3 = temp[2];
  send_info.data.temp4 = temp[3];

  //se a bomba estiver desligada, ignorar o valor do potenciometro
  if (pump_onoff) {
    if (switch_state) {
      send_info.data.pump_speed = remote_pumpspeed;
    }
    else {
      send_info.data.pump_speed = pot_value_mapped;
    }
  }
  else {
    send_info.data.pump_speed = 0.0;
  }


  send_info.data.hotflow = vazao_quente;
  send_info.data.coldflow = vazao_fria;
  bitWrite(send_info.data.bstatus, 0, pump_onoff);
  bitWrite(send_info.data.bstatus, 1, heater_onoff);
  bitWrite(send_info.data.bstatus, 2, switch_state);
  bitWrite(send_info.data.bstatus, 3, emergency_status);
}

float mapfloat(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

https://github.com/felipefonsecabh/ArduinoCode/blob/ArduinoNoNavigation/ArduinoCode.ino

My problem is ocasionally i'm receiving in master a crazy data.
For example:

```
Normal block data
[0, 0, 9, 66, 0, 192, 6, 66, 0, 128, 207, 65, 0, 0, 208, 65, 52, 171, 33, 64, 102, 102, 166, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 27]

Crazy data
[120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have already a open question about that same code: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/46637/interference-in-readings There are a number of problems with your code and I have not even mentioned them all.

Comment: The interference measurement os a diferent problem. I want to know , whats could be happening with my i2c packet, because doesn't make Sense ALL bytes with same value.

Comment: That could be a mismatch of command 54 between the master and the slave. It could be a bug in the master. You don't tell us who is showing the data of those 120's. In my opinion your sketch needs to be build up from the ground, step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this exact same problem, and it took me quite a while to track down the answer.

The I2C protocol is a very raw protocol that is inexpensive to implement, but is very susceptible to noise on the bus.  When I put the SCL and SDA lines on my oscilloscope, I saw that occasionally there were spikes of high frequency noise on both lines. These turned out to be EMF noise. Most of the spikes were rejected by glitch filters on the master and slave chips, but occasionally the spikes lasted too long for the glitch filters, and were then read as data or as clock pulses.

When this happens, the master and the slave get out of sync, often resulting in the slave holding SDA low while awaiting a clock pulse, while the master is waiting for the slave to release SDA so it can send a final NAK.

I2C has no concept of a timeout, so this state will last forever unless you detect it and force a resolution.

In the meantime, your sensor library does not check for Wire errors (it has no way of doing so) so it is returning invalid data.

When you see the invalid data, you can try to recover by temporarily taking control of the SCL and SDA pins yourself and toggling them as follows:

- Pulse the clock 9 times to force any slave that was sending data to
  finish sending the current byte, at which point it will release the
  SDA line. When SDA goes high, the slave will see the next clock pulse
  as a NAK, so it will stop sending any more bytes.  Any leftover clock
  pulses won't have any START marker, so will be ignored by the slaves.
- Then send a STOP condition (take CLK low, then take SDA low, then
  take CLK high, and finally allow SDA to transition low-> high while
  CLK is high. All masters and slaves on the bus should now be OK
  again.

Another failure mode can occur in which the slave believes it has received a WRITE command, and it may write to addresses that can put it into an unknown state. To recover from that state, first do the pulsing as above, and then just stop and restart that sensor using library calls.

Finally, there is a failure mode in which the master thinks another master has control of the bus. To recover from that state, first issue the pulses as above, then stop and restart Wire, and then stop and restart any frozen sensors.

It would be nice if all this functionality were in the Wire library, but as of today that's not the case so you'll have to do it yourself. Fortunately that's not too difficult -- it's only a dozen lines of code.

Good luck!